# OpenCV setup in Qt : my simple program returns an exception

Tags: qt, visual-c++, opencv, installation

Sorry for repeating a frequent question.
It is now a week that I am trying to set up openCV with Qt 5.0.2  or Microsoft VC++ express edition in my 32bit windows 7, with no success. 
now for QT : 
-It is QT 5.0.2 MinGW .
-It runs programs not using opencv successfully.

Now, the opencv lines of my .pro file is like this :

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\opencv\build\include"
LIBS += "C:\opencv\bin\bin\libopencv_core243.dll"
LIBS += "C:\opencv\bin\bin\libopencv_highgui243.dll"
```

This is because code like bellow results in error "not finding core.hpp":

```
LIBS += -LC:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib\
libopencv_core243 \
libopencv_highgui243 \
```

Now its autocomplete for opencv functions runs, and if you write :

```
cv::Mat im = cv::imread("D:\\Tulips.jpg");
```

there is no error.
But if after this you write :

```
cv::imshow("im",im);
```

It closes the program with exception code : c0000005
It even doesn't fall in "catch" of an exception handler.

The strange thing is that VC++ express is doing just the same.
I should mention that I have compiled opencv for MinGW myself, and the build was Ok because it works with Code::Blocks.
I used prebuilt opencv with my VC++ 10 , but that doesn't work either.
Pleaase help me!Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check if *im.data* is not null. Because c0000005 is access violation, that means you are using some invalid pointers, so show some more code or a better solution is to use a debugger and step-trough your code.

Comment: it even exits with this code if I write :  cout<<im . actually the pointer is null. but why? file which I want to read exists .

Comment: Make sure the path is correct and/or the file is not corrupted - i'm not experienced with opencv - maybe someone experienced with opencv can help you with that, if you confirm that is not a path/corrupted file issue.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure about the path. But now I cheked im.rows and im.cols and I see that it undrestands image dimensions. but if I write : cout <<im.at<cv::Vec3b>(1,1)[0] it returns strange characters. the image has three channels.

Comment: Id im.data is null is means that using that image can go back to access violation anytime, see the documentation on why that can be null: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imread
   Are you sure you don't have windows set to hide the extension for known types and your image is not actually named _Tulips.jpg_ and have the .jpg extension and the full name is not actually: _Tulips.jpg.jpg_?

Comment: No the path is ok. It reads the file and returns the rows and columns number . I see that im.data is null if the file path is wrong, but if the path is correct, even checking im.data is null or not causes crash.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer !!
It was all ablut the firewall.
My fireWall blocked the process and opencv couldn't access the memory.
When I used cvLoadImage() , it worked, but cv::imread() didn't.
I had added an exception for visual satudio but it seems that wasn't enough. Now my firewall is off and FINALLY EVERYTHING IS OKKK :) :)